# Windows and Firewalls

Tags: windows-7, firewall

1. If Simplewall is used to configure Windows Filtering Platform, will it still filter if Windows Firewall is disabled?
2. Does it log traffic like Wireshark?
3. Is there other free open source firewalls for Windows 7 and higher or MacOS?

Comment: Simplewall installs and configure his own WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) provider, it means that simplewall does not change any of Windows Firewall configuration, but Windows Firewall filters have high priority and processed first, so you would need to disable Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

1. Simplewall is really just a easier tool to configure the native Windows firewall (Win7-10).  It is not a firewall itself, it merely manages the Windows firewall.
2. It can log some traffic, but Wireshark would do significantly more.
3. There are a handful of free/opensource firewalls, you can do a web search and find many options.  Generally the native Windows firewall is effective for common restrictions.